# Create a particular JSON Structure in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm having trouble creating a specific structure in JSON with Swift. I use Swifty JSON for parsing but I can't figure out how to create one.

I have this array which is filled by Id's and quantity Ints of products in a shopping basket . I need to get the array into my JSON but I don't know how.

If you could help me with this I would be very glad :)

```
    var productArray = Array<(id: Int,quantity: Int)>()

    let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "order": 1,
        "client" : 1,
        "plats": [
            for product in productArray
            {
            "id": product.id
            "quantity": product.quantity
            }
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Is this code compiling ?

Comment: Nope, just "Expected expression in container literal" at the for line, I can't figure out how to do this

Comment: You've got a `for` loop `[` and `]`, that's definitely not allowed. What did you want the value of they `plats` key to be?

Comment: I want to have "plats" who looks like http://puu.sh/hVinh/39d4e4e11c.png ! You know like an Array inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just start looping through stuff while defining your dictionary. Here's another approach.

First, create your array:

```
var productArray = Array<(id: Int,quantity: Int)>()
```

Add some products (for testing):

```
productArray += [(123, 1000)]
productArray += [(456, 50)]
```

Map this array into a new array of dictionaries:

```
let productDictArray = productArray.map { (product) -> [String : Int] in
    [
        "id": product.id,
        "quantity": product.quantity
    ]
}
```

Use the new mapped array in your JSON object:

```
let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "order": 1,
    "client" : 1,
    "plats": productDictArray
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to do any kind of looping/condition making block of codes while creating `Array`'s or `Dictionary`. For that you need to execute that piece of code outside, create a variable and use it.

Do try this way.

```
var productArray = Array<(id: Int,quantity: Int)>()

    var prods = [[String:Int]]()
    for product in productArray
    {
        var eachDict = [String:Int]()
        eachDict["id"] =  product.id
        eachDict["quantity"] = product.quantity
        prods.append(eachDict)
    }

    let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "order": 1,
        "client" : 1,
        "plats": prods
    ]
```